# Kafka Streams Rate limit Consumption

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to limit my consumption rate from a topic based on a condition.
For example:

If a message contains: "foo"
I want to consume not more than 5 messages per second (Globally - meaning even if there are multiple instances of the consumers running on my server).

If a message contains: "bar"
I want to consume not more than 2 messages per second (Globally - meaning even if there are multiple instances of the consumers running on my server).

And so on.

Is this possible to do it using KStreams (Kafka Streams)?

An alternative way is to do it using a traditional kafka consumer and code the rate limiting by managing the state in a store like Redis. But I'm avoiding to reinvent the wheel if Kafka Streams natively offer this capability.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you could do this with Kafka Streams. It abstracts too many lower level consumer concepts. For what you describe, you need to control the "poll()" behavior which is "hard coded" inside Kafka Streams runtime, and you cannot change it.